# Apple's Sketch Source code NSArrayController Binding

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings

I've been pulling my hair out over this for ages, in Apple's source code for their Sketch App, available here: developer.apple.com/samplecode they are binding an NSArrayController to an Array in the NSDocument.

When they do this in the NSView of the NSWindowController:

```
[mutableGraphics insertObject:_creatingGraphic atIndex:0];
```

it calls this code in the NSDocument:

```
- (void)insertGraphics:(NSArray *)graphics atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes {
```

My question is how is this done? I want to be able to do this programmatically, there seems to be some kind of magic going on here.

I am binding my NSArrayController like this:

```
[_componentsController bind:NSContentArrayBinding toObject:self withKeyPath:@"document.components" options:NULL];
```

But I have no idea how it calls the custom method instead.

A couple more days at this and all my hair will be gone, any pointers/tips greatly welcome.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out. The NSDocument class needed to be KVC compliant, therefore I needed the following methods:

```
- (NSArray *)components {
- (void)insertComponents:(NSArray *)components atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes
- (void)removeComponentsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes
```